# Why is Auth::check() returning false here?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to customize the 404 error page , so I made a 404.blade.php view and it works fine, however my view has a navbar and some `@if` statements which check if user is logged in. In all other pages, it works correctly, however in 404, it returns false, and a guest navbar is shown. How can I change that behavior if it's even possible?

Here is my kernel.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Show your `kernel.php` code for `$middleware `

Comment: edited question to include kernel

Comment: Try to swap `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from `middlewareGroups` to `middlewareGroups` and check. Might this work

Comment: perfect, works. thank you! btw, you meant: from `middlewareGroups` to `middleware` :)

Comment: Ok, let me place it as answer so other can get the help

Comment: Answer added, please accept it so other user can find the correct answer. Glad to help :)

Comment: @MikoMi, AddWebSolutionPvtLtd > Answered, I think he mean to  protected $middleware array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made below change into your `kernal.php`

Remove `StartSession::class` line from `protected $middlewareGroups` and add the same line into `protected $middleware`.

This might work